# segmentation fault while freeing memory

Tags: c

Here is a program I made this program has segmentation fault I checked it in gdb in the second last of code      `free(somepath);` .I do not have any reason for why is this segmentation fault coming?
Some one please suggest some thing.

```
#include<dirent.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
char *directs[20], *files[20];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int count = 0;

void printdir(char *);
int count_dirs(char *);
int count_files(char *);
void new_printdir(int ,int ,char *);
int main()
{
    char startdir[20];
    printf("Scanning user directories\n");
    scanf("%s", startdir);
    printdir(startdir);
}

void printdir(char *dir)
{


    DIR *dp = opendir(dir);
    int nDirs, nFiles, nD, nF;

    nDirs = 0;
    nFiles = 0;
    nD = 0;
    nF = 0;
    if (dp) {
        struct dirent *entry = 0;
        struct stat statBuf;

        nDirs = count_dirs(dir);
        nFiles = count_files(dir);



  new_printdir(nDirs,nFiles,dir);


        while ((entry = readdir(dp)) != 0) {
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0) {
                continue;
            }

    char *     filepath = malloc(strlen(dir) + strlen(entry->d_name) + 2);
            if (filepath) {
                sprintf(filepath, "%s/%s", dir, entry->d_name);
                if (lstat(filepath, &statBuf) == 0) {
                    if (S_ISDIR(statBuf.st_mode)) {
                    printdir(filepath);
                        }
                    else {
                    }
                }

            }    

            free(filepath);
        }        //2nd while

        closedir(dp);
    }

    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, cannot open directory %s\n", dir);
    }

}                //printdir

int count_dirs(char *dir)
{
    DIR *dp = opendir(dir);
    int nD;
    nD = 0;
    if (dp) {
        struct dirent *entry = 0;
        struct stat statBuf;

        while ((entry = readdir(dp)) != 0) {
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0) {
                continue;
            }

            char *filepath =  malloc(strlen(dir) + strlen(entry->d_name) + 2);

            if (filepath) {
                sprintf(filepath, "%s/%s", dir, entry->d_name);

                if (lstat(filepath, &statBuf) != 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "File Not found? %s\n",filepath);
                }

                if (S_ISDIR(statBuf.st_mode)) {
                    nD++;

                } else {
                    continue;
                }

                free(filepath);
            }
        }

        closedir(dp);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, cannot open directory %s\n", dir);
    }
    return nD;
}

int count_files(char *dir)
{
    DIR *dp = opendir(dir);
    int nF;
    nF = 0;
    if (dp) {
        struct dirent *entry = 0;
        struct stat statBuf;

        while ((entry = readdir(dp)) != 0) {
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0) {
                continue;
            }

            char *filepath =
                malloc(strlen(dir) + strlen(entry->d_name) + 2);

            if (filepath) {
                sprintf(filepath, "%s/%s", dir, entry->d_name);

                if (lstat(filepath, &statBuf) != 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "File Not found? %s\n",    filepath);
                }

                if (S_ISDIR(statBuf.st_mode)) {

                    continue;
                } else {
                    nF++;

                }

                free(filepath);
            }
        }

        closedir(dp);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, cannot open file %s\n", dir);
    }
    return nF;
}

void new_printdir(int nDirs,int nFiles,char *dir)
{

      struct dirent **namelist;
        DIR *dop;
        int i, j,t,re,nD,nF;

        char userd[20],*somepath;

       i = scandir(dir, &namelist, 0, alphasort);
        t=0;

        if (i < 0)
                perror ("Scandir failed to open directory I hope you understand \n");
        else {
                for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if(strcmp(".",namelist[j]->d_name)==0||strcmp("..",namelist[j]->d_name)==0)
                continue;
              somepath = malloc(strlen(dir)+strlen(namelist[j]->d_name)+2);
                  sprintf(somepath,"%s/%s",dir,namelist[j]->d_name);
                        dop=opendir(somepath);

                        if(dop)
                         {

                nD++;
                            if ((nDirs-nD)<3)    
                        {printf("%s ",namelist[j]->d_name);}
                          }
                     else {
                nF++;
                if ((nFiles-nF)<3)    
                printf("%s ",namelist[j]->d_name);
              }
            closedir(dop);
                        free(namelist[j]);
                }
        }
        free(namelist);
 free(somepath);

}
```

Why is this segmentation fault happening this is not clear to me.
What can I do to get rid of it?

Comment: 2) Indent your code correctly. That's a mess

Comment: Global variables `i` and `j` are (a) appallingly named and (b) mercifully unused - there are local variables `i` and `j` in `new_printdir()` which is the only place the names seem to be used.  I think `count` is also unused.  I think `directs` and `files` are similarly unused - which is good since the fixed sizes are rather small.  Creating global variables is not a good idea; leaving them around unused is worse.

Comment: a very similar problem was addressed in your previous Question as well. Do you even read what is posted here?

Comment: do not destroy your question after it is answered; people need to be able to see the original question so that the answers make sense to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you are not guaranteed to allocate memory and assign it to `somepath` (you also fail to free somepath except for the last iteration of the loop). You should put your `free(somepath)` statement at the end of the for-loop, and you should initialize `somepath` to NULL both at the very beginning of the function and at the start of each for loop to avoid similar careless errors.

Comment: Good spotting on the leak.  The variable, though, should be declared at the top of the loop, not at the top of the function (and the free should be therefore only be inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You're not initializing the somepath variable - it has an undefined value unless the malloc() executes (i.e. for empty folders). You should initialize it to NULL at the place of definition.

Answer (score 1):

You do not initialize somepath to 0 (NULL), but you could under some circumstances release the value.  This means you release a random value - which is not a good idea.

Comment: @Bond: There are still memory leaks in the code - notably from scandir() because the code does not release the memory for the "." and ".." directory entries.  It is possible to get it leak free (I've done it), but you have to take great care.  I would argue that the output formatting needs work too.

Comment: Ok I got your point.The formatting here on forum is difficult how ever it works on vim on my machine.